# Why does QPainter scale (cosmetic) points in one axis although they should not be affected?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm drawing lines and points in my Qt application and having trouble with what seems like a scaling bug in QPainter. My lines work just fine but points are affected by transformations for certain scalings although the pen is set to be "cosmetic". What bothers me the most is that only a single axis (the x-axis) seems to be affected. Otherwise I could nail it down to some floating-point precision issues within the transformation/matrix code.

Qt versions: **Qt 4.8 for embedded**, **Qt 5.4 for Desktop**, **Qt 5.6 LTS for Desktop**

Here are some renderings that should actually all look the same (like the most left one):

[image]

I have an RenderArea derived from QWidget which simply draws one of the images above. RenderArea is simply instantiated in main() and shown. The code is trivial there so here is the relevant painting code:

```
void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* /* event */)
{
    const qreal scaleFactor = 0.01;

    // Define a "unit" square
    std::vector<QPointF> points;
    points.push_back(QPointF(0, 0));
    points.push_back(QPointF(1.0, 0));
    points.push_back(QPointF(1.0, 1.0));
    points.push_back(QPointF(0, 1.0));

    // Build a scaled version of the points
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        points[i] *= scaleFactor;
    }

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.save();

    // Scale the painter so that every square takes 100 pixels
    // in screen space regardless of the scaleFactor:
    painter.scale(100.0 / scaleFactor, 100.0 / scaleFactor);

    QPen pointPen(Qt::blue, 10);
    pointPen.setCosmetic(true);
    painter.setPen(pointPen);
    painter.drawPoints(points.data(), points.size());

    QPen linePen(Qt::red, 5);
    linePen.setCosmetic(true);
    painter.setPen(linePen);
    painter.drawPolyline(points.data(), points.size());

    painter.restore();
}
```

The example is based on the basicdrawing example coming with Qt but I stripped everything away to highlight the problem.

- Why does this issue arise?
- Why does it only arise for one axis?

Comment: It's a Qt bug, I'm not sure if it has been reported or not. It should be easy to fix, though.

Comment: @KubaOber Are you sure that it's a bug? I'm a bit confused since this is such a basic drawing/transformation operation. In case that you are aware of such a problem, do you have any suggestion on how to ship around this problem? I really want to omit patching my Qt version.

Comment: The documentation for `drawPoints` states: "Draws the first pointCount points in the array points using the current pen's color.". It is not mentioned that other attributes of the pen are respected.

Comment: @FrozenTarzan It's totally a bug. The documentation is insufficient, but the behavior observed would be incorrect. There is, essentially, a point-drawing kludge in Qt that's erroneous for cosmetic pens. It's a basic drawing operation, but people who ran into this problem either assumed their mistake and found some other way of doing it, or they patched their own copy of Qt to fix the bug, but in all cases you might ask how many people did what you do - and it may be not too many. It's a rather specific case.

Comment: And of course the workaround is not to use `drawPoints`, and implement a better line-drawn point approximation. It won't be pretty, because line sizes do scale. So you'll end up having to do something else. Perhaps draw a device-scaled `QImage`.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks a lot! Unfortunate to hear, but thanks for the input! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this topic I'd like to add a reference to another stackoverflow question:
[Why does QPainter::drawPoint draw a horizontal line segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194141/why-does-qpainterdrawpoint-draw-a-horizontal-line-segment?rq=1)

It seems to be a bug in Qt which was filed here:
[QPainter::drawPoints draws line segments instead of points](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70409)

As pointed out in the comments this bug might be overcome by writing own code for drawing points, by patching Qt, drawing images instead of points or by using drawEllipse.