# Why does QPainter::drawPoint draw a horizontal line segment?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm trying to draw a 3-pixel large point with `QPainter`. But the following code instead draws a horizontal line with width of 3 pixels.

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>

int main()
{
    const int w=1000, h=1000;
    QImage img(w, h, QImage::Format_RGBX8888);
    {
        QPainter p(&img);
        p.fillRect(0,0,w,h,Qt::black);
        p.scale(w,h);
        p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 3./w, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
        p.drawPoint(QPointF(0.1,0.1));
    }
    img.save("test.png");
}
```

Here's the top left corner of the resulting image:

[image: line instead of a point]

I am expecting to get a point which is red circle, or at least a square — but instead I get this line segment. If I comment out `p.scale(w,h)` and draw the point with width `3` (instead of `3./w`) at position `(100,100)`, then I get a small mostly symmetric 3-pixel in height and width point.

What's going on? Why do I get a line segment instead of point as expected? And how to fix it, without resorting to drawing an ellipse or to avoiding `QPainter::scale`?

I'm using Qt 5.10.0 on Linux x86 with g++ 5.5.0. The same happens on Qt 5.5.1.

Comment: Do you want a three pixel large dot or a dash? If you want dash then you should have used Qt::DotLine instead of SolidLine. Edit your question to make your objective clear

Comment: @Gurushant I though the first sentence already says that I want a point. Isn't _point_ a synonym for _dot_?

Comment: Yeah of course, but later you said "then I get normal point, not a "dash"". I don't understand what you meant here.

Comment: @Gurushant OK, I've tried to clarify, please see if it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `QPaintEngineEx::drawPoints` renders points as line segments of length `1/63.`. See the following code from [qtbase/src/gui/painting/qpaintengineex.cpp](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/painting/qpaintengineex.cpp#n846) in the Qt sources:

```
void QPaintEngineEx::drawPoints(const QPointF *points, int pointCount)
{
    QPen pen = state()->pen;
    if (pen.capStyle() == Qt::FlatCap)
        pen.setCapStyle(Qt::SquareCap);

    if (pen.brush().isOpaque()) {
        while (pointCount > 0) {
            int count = qMin(pointCount, 16);
            qreal pts[64];
            int oset = -1;
            for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
                pts[++oset] = points[i].x();
                pts[++oset] = points[i].y();
                pts[++oset] = points[i].x() + 1/63.;
                pts[++oset] = points[i].y();
            }
            QVectorPath path(pts, count * 2, qpaintengineex_line_types_16, QVectorPath::LinesHint);
            stroke(path, pen);
            pointCount -= 16;
            points += 16;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<pointCount; ++i) {
            qreal pts[] = { points[i].x(), points[i].y(), points[i].x() + qreal(1/63.), points[i].y() };
            QVectorPath path(pts, 2, 0);
            stroke(path, pen);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `pts[++oset] = points[i].x() + 1/63.;` line in the opaque brush branch. This is the second vertex of the path — shifted with respect to the desired position of the point.

This explains why the line extends to the right of the position requested and why it depends on the scale. So, it seems the code in the OP isn't wrong for an ideal `QPainter` implementation, but just has come across a Qt bug (be it in the implementation of the method or in its documentation).

So the conclusion: one *has* to work around this problem by either using different scale, or drawing ellipses, or drawing line segments with much smaller lengths than what `QPainter::drawPoints` does.

I've reported this as [QTBUG-70409](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70409).

Comment: This explains why! Thanks, I could not concentrate on other work because of this

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not been able to pin point why exactly the problem occurs, I have got relatively close to the solution. The problem lies with scaling. I did a lots of trial and error with different scaling and width of point with the below code.

```
const int w=500, h=500;
const int scale = 100;
float xPos = 250;
float yPos = 250;
float widthF = 5;
QImage img(w, h, QImage::Format_RGBX8888);
{
    QPainter p(&img);
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    p.fillRect(0,0,w,h,Qt::black);
    p.scale(scale, scale);
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, widthF/(scale), Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
    p.drawPoint(QPointF(xPos/scale, yPos/scale));
}
img.save("test.png");
```

The above code produces the image
[image]

My observations are
1) Due to high scaling, the point (which is just 3 pixel wide) is not able to scale proportionally at lower width (width of point), if you set width as something like 30 the round shape is visible.
2) If you want to keep the width of point low then you have to decrease the scaling.
 Sadly I can not explain why at high scaling it is not expanding proportionally.

Comment: I've found the culprit, see my answer.